# JOIN two sql SELECT statements where one has single record and other has multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have tow tables, the first is mda_alert_info and the second is key_contacts_info. For each alert set up there may be multiple corresponding contacts. Both tables are linked by 3 columns mda_id, stage_id and ref_number and during the query I will have to pass figures values for them

How do I get all what I want from both tables in one statement. Below are the individual SELECT statements.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `mda_name`, `project_name`, `ipc_id` FROM `mda_alert_info` WHERE `stage_id`=1 AND `mda_id`=2 AND `ref_number`= '444'");
```

This will always return one record

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `contact_role`, `contact_email`, `contact_ph_number` FROM `key_contacts_info` WHERE `stage_id`=1 AND `mda_id`=2 AND `role`=0 AND `ref_number`='444'");
```

This may return multiple records

I tried for a while and couldn't get it to work so I tried adding another field called 'me' to both tables which is basically concatting mda_id and stage_id strings then I tried the query below.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT key_contacts_info.contact_role, key_contacts_info.contact_email, key_contacts_info.contact_ph_number, mda_alert_info.mda_name, mda_alert_info.project_name, mda_alert_info.ipc_id FROM key_contacts_info LEFT JOIN mda_alert_info ON key_contacts_info.me = mda_alert_info.me WHERE stage_id=1 AND mda_id=2 AND role=0 AND ref_number='444'");
```

But it's still not working. What am I doing wrong and how do I get it to work.

UPDATE:

Sorry but I should clarify something on the relationship between the tables the three columns exist on each table but are not primary keys on either of the tables

Comment: I stated it above, there are 3 columns mda_id, stage_id and ref_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    mda_alert_info a
        INNER JOIN key_contacts_info b
            ON  a.mda_id = b.mda_id AND
                a.stage_id = b.stage_id AND
                a.ref_number = b.ref_number 
WHERE   b.role = 0 AND
        a.stage_id = 1 AND 
        a.mda_id = 2 AND 
        a.ref_number = '444'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: I would need to give values for ref_number, mda_id and stage_id

Comment: Sorry but I should clarify something on the relationship between the tables the three columns exist on each table but are not primary keys on either of the tables

Comment: so you are concerned on the performance? add a compund column index, `ALTER TABLE mda_alert_info INDEX (mda_id, stage_id, ref_number)` AND `ALTER TABLE key_contacts_info INDEX (mda_id, stage_id, ref_number)`

Comment: @Amanni it prevent the query from executing `FULL TABLE SCAN` causing low performance on large databases.

Comment: Alright, but my issue first is getting the query to work at the answer give above doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    a.mda_name,
    a.project_name,
    a.lpc_id,
    k.contact_role,
    k.contact_email,
    k.contact_ph_number
from mda_alert_info a
join key_contacts_info k
    on a.state_id = k.state_id
    and a.mda_id = k.mda_id
    and a.ref_number = k.ref_number
where a.state_id = 1
  and a.mda_id = 2
  and a.ref_number = '444'
  and k.role = 0
;
```